# How to merge together similar XML documents using jQuery?

Tags: jquery, xml, jquery-ui, autocomplete

If anyone read my last question, this is somewhat of a continuation of it.

AFAIK, when using jQuery UI's Autocomplete ability to grab data from an XML file as its data source, you can only do it from one file in the Ajax call.

http://www.finalfantasyunion.com/includes/xml/games.xml

I'm planning to have a series of XML files like that with different data but the same items -> item tag format.

I could have a MySQL database which I query data from (where the file is really an PHP file but reports itself as a XML file once I've gotten the data) dynamically create an XML file, but if possible I'd rather not have this require a database connection if at all possible --- that way other staff members could edit the file easily as new games are announced/etc.

EDIT: The reason I don't want everything in one file is because I plan to use autocomplete elsewhere in the backend, and I'll only need specific data for some sections.

Comment: Regardless of usage, this should still be done server-side, you can combine files server-side without a database connection :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need a custom source-option implementation for reading the xml response, so you could just extend that and merge the result of multiple requests on the clientside.

Or put a proxy inbetween on the server-side and do the merging there, probably much more effective.